Second group cohomology of a twisted fundamental group
Let $X$ be a smooth hyperbolic projective curve defined over $\mathbb{Z}[1/S]$, where $S$ is a finite set of primes, and let $\pi:=\pi_1^{\text{ét}}(X, \overline{b})$ denote its étale fundamental group based at a $\mathbb{Z}[1/S]$-integral point $b$.
Let $\overline{\pi}:=\pi_1^{\text{ét}}(\overline{X}, \overline{b})$, the fundamental exact sequence reads off as
$1\longrightarrow \overline{\pi}\longrightarrow \pi\longrightarrow G_S\longrightarrow 1$, where $G_S$ is the Galois group of the maximal $\mathbb{Q}$ extension unramified outside $S$.
Let $\pi'$ denote the semidirect product of $\overline{\pi}$ and $G_S$, where $G_S$ acts on $\overline{\pi}$ with the inverse action, that is, we apply $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ before conjugating.
I am trying to understand what may be said about the $\mathbb{Q}_p$-dimension of $H^2(\pi', \mathbb{Q}_p)$ with the trivial action.
I understand the question may appear unmotivated, but I would like to know under what conditions this $H^2$ is one dimensional.
Any reading recommendation/references/suggestions would be appreciated.

I don't think the inverse action is an action, since $g \mapsto g^{-1}$ is not a group homomorphism.

What I meant by 'inverse action' is that I consider $G_S$ acting on $\overline{\pi}$ via $\overline{\gamma}\mapsto g^{-1}\overline{\gamma}g$ in $\pi'$ versus $\overline{\gamma}\mapsto g\overline{\gamma}g^{-1}$ in $\pi$.

I understand your comment means that $\pi$ and $\pi'$ should not be isomorphic in general. Corrected accordingly.

That's not what my comment means. Semidirect products are usually defined with left actions $\varphi_g (\gamma) $ satisfying $\varphi_{gh}(\gamma)= \varphi_g (\varphi_h(\gamma))$. With the definition $\varphi_g(\gamma) = g \gamma g^{-1}$ this is always satisifed. However for $\varphi_g(\gamma) = g^{-1} \gamma g$ this is not satisfied since $\varphi_{g}( \varphi_h(\gamma)) = \varphi_g ( h^{-1} \gamma h) =g^{-1} h^{-1} \gamma hg \neq (gh)^{-1} \gamma gh = \varphi_{gh}(\gamma)$. So the semidirect product $\pi'$ does not exist at all.
